# Hidden textures

Tags: c++, textures, sdl

How do the developers of games "hide" textures from editing. For example in game called Faster Than Light which is made in c++ using SDL. There is no directory with graphic files. How to "hide" textures?

Comment: There is no answer how to do it .

Comment: Yes there is, multiple actually. There are multiple techniques mentioned that can be used to hide the assets. However, I'm not convinced that it's worth the trouble to hide the assets. Why take the fun away from potential modders?